# How to go to current location by pressing a button?

Tags: flutter, dart, location, mapbox

I'm making a mobile application (flutter) and have already added a mapbox map and displayed the current location on the map. How to add a button that, when clicked, will take you to the current location? I also had a problem with launching the program on my phone, the install button is visible on the phone and nothing happens when I click on it.
I can show my mapbox access token and url if you want.

main.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_map/flutter_map.dart';
import 'package:latlong2/latlong.dart';
import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart';
import 'package:flutter_map_location_marker/flutter_map_location_marker.dart';

void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      home: new MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => new _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
        appBar: new AppBar(title: new Text('MapBox')),
        body: new FlutterMap(
          options: new MapOptions(
              initialCenter: new LatLng(56.946285, 24.105078),
              minZoom: 6,
              maxZoom: 20),
          children: [
            TileLayer(
              urlTemplate:
                  'url',
              // userAgentPackageName: 'com.example.app',
              additionalOptions: {
                'accessToken':
                    'token'
              },
            ),
            RichAttributionWidget(
              attributions: [
                TextSourceAttribution(
                  'OpenStreetMap contributors',
                  onTap: () => launchUrl(
                      Uri.parse('https://openstreetmap.org/copyright')),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            CurrentLocationLayer(
              followOnLocationUpdate: FollowOnLocationUpdate.always,
              turnOnHeadingUpdate: TurnOnHeadingUpdate.never,
              style: LocationMarkerStyle(
                marker: const DefaultLocationMarker(
                  // color: Colors.blue,
                  child: Icon(
                    Icons.navigation,
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                ),
                markerSize: const Size(40, 40),
                markerDirection: MarkerDirection.heading,
              ),
            )
          ],
        ));
  }
}
```

pubspec.yaml

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_map: ^6.0.1
  geolocator: ^10.1.0
  latlong2: ^0.9.0
  location: ^5.0.3
  url_launcher: ^6.2.1
  flutter_map_location_marker: ^8.0.2
```

add a button that, when clicked, will take you to the current location.

Answer (score 0):

To move to current location, you need to make use of the MapController.

`MapController mapController = MapController();`

Then assign this controller to the mapController parameter of Flutter Map.

You then use geolocator to get the user's current location and then use mapController to navigate to that location.

```
          onPressed: () {
              Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(
                      desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high)
                  .then((pickedCurrentLocation) {
                setState(() {
                  currentLocation = pickedCurrentLocation;
                });
                mapController.move(
                    LatLng(currentLocation.latitude,
                        currentLocation.longitude),
                    6);
              });
            }
```

This should move the user to their current location.

Full code sample below:

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  var currentLocation;

  MapController mapController = MapController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('MapBox')),
        body: FlutterMap(
          mapController: mapController,
          options: const MapOptions(
              initialCenter: LatLng(56.946285, 24.105078),
              minZoom: 6,
              maxZoom: 20),
          children: [
            TileLayer(
              urlTemplate:
                  'url',
              // userAgentPackageName: 'com.example.app',
              additionalOptions: {
                'accessToken':
                    'token'
              },
            ),
            RichAttributionWidget(
              attributions: [
                TextSourceAttribution(
                  'OpenStreetMap contributors',
                  onTap: () => launchUrl(
                      Uri.parse('https://openstreetmap.org/copyright')),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            CurrentLocationLayer(
              // followOnLocationUpdate: FollowOnLocationUpdate.always,
              turnOnHeadingUpdate: TurnOnHeadingUpdate.never,
              style: const LocationMarkerStyle(
                marker: DefaultLocationMarker(
                  // color: Colors.blue,
                  child: Icon(
                    Icons.navigation,
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                ),
                markerSize: Size(40, 40),
                markerDirection: MarkerDirection.heading,
              ),
            ),
            TextButton(
                child: Text("Go home"),
                onPressed: () {
                  Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(
                          desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high)
                      .then((pickedCurrentLocation) {
                    setState(() {
                      currentLocation = pickedCurrentLocation;
                    });
                    mapController.move(
                        LatLng(currentLocation.latitude,
                            currentLocation.longitude),
                        6);
                  });
                })
          ],
        ));
  }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi, the button appears, but it doesn't return to the current location. Where could the error be?

Comment: Did you comment this line out `followOnLocationUpdate: FollowOnLocationUpdate.always,`?